# QuickBlox: How to keep alive app in background?

Tags: xmpp, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox SDk for chat app. When app goes to background mode, I could not receive chat messages. So I want to keep alive app in background mode.

I know the way to keep alive app in background for **[VOIP based app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)**.

Also I got a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257580/iphone-xmpp-app-run-background) for XMPP to support background mode. But for that we need to interact with XMPP framework but with QuickBlox SDK we don't need to directly interact with XMPP frameworks.

So, What is the possible way to keep alive app in background using QuickBlox SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be online in XMPP while your device send XMPP presence.

```
[[QBChat instance] sendPresence];
```

After 90 seconds from last presence session is closed.

I think you can create background task with presence timer (but this will work for 10 minutes. After that time will spend you can try recreate background task for next 10 mins and etc., but I don't check if this work). This is **Perform finite-length tasks** from Ray's site.