# XMPP App send message with when app enter background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, xmpp, apple-push-notifications

I use the apns to push messages to my app, when it run in background. But APNS sometimes delay is very serious.

So how about try to set VOIP and set `xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES;` in order to replace APNS when app run at background ？or we combine the two approaches use.

What i consider are the following points :
1.how long a app can run in background,when we set a VOIP?
2.does anyone have succeeded when use VOIP that appStore did't reject ?

ps: sorry for my English,and Here's a reference [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257580/iphone-xmpp-app-run-background)! 
THX in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement real VOIP calls to be approved with VOIP capabilities. Check the following XMPP VOIP extensions: [Jingle](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html) and [Jingle RTP](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0167.html). Another way: use SIP with XMPP, check [CUSAX](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7081) RFC.