# ios 7 fetch offline message from xmpp server

Tags: ios7, xmpp, voip, background-fetch

I am developing chat application using XMPP protocol.
My development target is iOS 7.0
Every think is working fine user can able to communicate only when they are online.
But I want to notify user message has come when they are offline.

I have tried [iphone XMPP App run background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257580/iphone-xmpp-app-run-background)
But it doesn’t work for me.

First think it is possible or not? 
Using what VIOP, background fetch or some other way?

If yes please let me know. how?.

Comment: I wish my think was working fine :(

Answer (score 0):

The thread you are referring mention declaring that your app is a VoIP app to be allowed to constantly run in background.

It is technically possible but has two drawbacks:

- If your application does not do voip, Apple will reject it (as misleading).
- Battery consumption will be excessive as you will stay connected.

The state of the art is to fallback to Apple push notification service when the TCP connection between the client and the server is not established. This is battery efficient and provide a very good way to notify the user of new messages.

Comment: but how i integrate push notification in Openfire(XMPP) ?