# XMPP Modules kill app in background

Tags: ios, background, xmpp, xmppframework

I am implementing a chat app using XMPP framework. Now the problem is that the app is getting killed when the app goes to sleep mode and the phone is locked after 5-10 mins. Now when I comment the XMPP code then the app is running. Could anybody help me explain why is it happening. How could I resolve the issue or what could be the cause of the same.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5257580/113848) help?

Comment: No it is still getting killed. Could you let me know why is it getting killed when it goes to sleep mode?

Comment: Hi,Have you you found the solution, I am facing same issue like you are facing?